# "Specified cast is not valid" when populating DataTable from OracleDataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: c#, oracle, casting, datatable, decimal

I can't seem to find this question anywhere on Google (or StackOverflow), which really surprised me, so I'm putting it on here to help others in the same situation.

I have a SQL query which runs fine on Oracle Sql Developer, but when I run it through `C#` using`adapter.Fill(table)` to get the results, I get `Specified cast is not valid` errors (`System.InvalidCastException`).

Here is cut-down version of the C# code:

```
var resultsTable = new DataTable();

using (var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    var rows = adapter.Fill(resultsTable);  // exception thrown here, but sql runs fine on Sql Dev

    return resultsTable;
}
```

And here is a simplified version of the SQL:

```
SELECT acct_no, market_value/mv_total
FROM myTable
WHERE NVL(market_value, 0) != 0
AND NVL(mv_total, 0) != 0
```

If I remove the division clause, it doesn't error - so it's specific to that.  However, both market_value and `mv_total` are of type Number(19,4) and I can see that the Oracle adapter is expecting a decimal, so what cast is taking place?  Why does it work on SqlDev but not in C#?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Answering my own question:

So it seems that the Oracle number type can hold many more decimal places than the C# decimal type and if Oracle is trying to return more than C# can hold, it throws the InvalidCastException.

Solution?

In your sql, round any results that might have too many decimal places to something sensible.  So I did this:

```
SELECT acct_no, ROUND(market_value/mv_total, 8)  -- rounding this division solves the problem
FROM myTable
WHERE NVL(market_value, 0) != 0
AND NVL(mv_total, 0) != 0
```

And it worked.

The take away is: Incompatibility between Oracle number type and C# decimal.  Restrict your Oracle decimal places to avoid the invalid cast exceptions.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution to your own problem. probably saved me a couple of hours (and gray hair^^). But is there a way that avoids rounding numbers within the query?

Comment: I know this post is kinda old, but this just happened to me, and rounding didn't help. In my case, I had some very high values. For completeness  (hopefully not needed for market values :-) ) write: ROUND(GREATEST(LEAST(market_value/mv_total,7.9E28),-7.9E28),8)

Comment: You brother saved my day

Comment: You saved my life with this. Thanks!

Comment: while I did not follow this fixed. I salute you for posting it. I was running in circles for hours.

Comment: Ouch, Bitten again.  So I did this: SELECT ....,  ,to_char(Round(b.Length,2),'9,999.00')     AS Feet,... from <some_table>  which not only addressed the overly precise return value but also formatted the data in a tidy way, since I only needed it for reporting purposes.

Comment: For consistency I use a function taking the input value and returning a string to defend against this problem... plus it will round and format as desired.  If I knew how I could post it but it is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 9):

I know this thread is really old.. However I had a similar issue.

The best solution I have to use the Oracle method TO_BINARY_DOUBLE on Oracle Decimal column

Answer (score 3):

A more convenient method to solve this issue is to use `SuppressGetDecimalInvalidCastException` in the OracleDataAdapter:

```
var table = new DataTable();
await using var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
var command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection)
{
    CommandTimeout = commandTimeout
};

using var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command) { SuppressGetDecimalInvalidCastException = true };
await Task.Run(() => adapter.Fill(table));
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/DataReaderSuppressGetDecimalInvalidCastException.html):

> This property specifies whether to suppress the InvalidCastException
> and return a rounded-off 28 precision value if the Oracle NUMBER value
> has more than 28 precision.

Comment: I ran into this same issue using OracleDataReader. Used the SuppressGetDecimalInvalidCastException property on the reader, and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered already, but I also found another alternative that I use as well.  I used a CAST on the field that was giving me troubles.

Based on OP's SELECT command:

```
SELECT acct_no, CAST((market_value/mv_total) AS DECIMAL(14,4))  -- CAST to decimal here
FROM myTable
WHERE NVL(market_value, 0) != 0
AND NVL(mv_total, 0) != 0
```