# OracleDataReader InvalidCastException: "Specified cast is not valid" on Decimal Types in .NET

Tags: .net, oracle-manageddataaccess

When using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader` and then calling `reader.GetValue(i)`, we get the exception above.

This can be simulated using this query:

```
SELECT 1/3 as foo FROM DUAL
```

The problem arises when the oracle data is of Oracle type `Decimal`, and the precision in the data exceeds the number of decimal places in the .NET decimal.  And the main issue is that `reader.GetValue(i)` does this, so you have no control over the fact that it throws this error internally.

I actually have a workaround, which I will post as an answer since I've hit this a number of times in the past, and the web does not have a good answer yet.

Related:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4017980

["Specified cast is not valid" when populating DataTable from OracleDataAdapter.Fill()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935716/specified-cast-is-not-valid-when-populating-datatable-from-oracledataadapter-f)

Comment: Wouldn't `SELECT 1/3 as foo FROM DUAL` result in `0`? (Maybe Oracle automatically casts to a decimal or float?)

Comment: Couldn't you use another method... like reader.GetDecimal() or something like that?

Comment: @douglas.kirschman,  GetDecimal fails as well, unfortunately.

Comment: @Igor, Oracle does cast these properly, so you get 0.33333...

Comment: @DanielWilliams Just encountered this issue myself. You mentioned in your question that you would post a workaround as an answer but never did.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this took so long to post @Jeff!  The solution is to get the field type, and if it is decimal, then to call  the oracle explicit method GetOracleDecimal()

```
if (reader.GetFieldType(i).Name.ToUpper() == "DECIMAL")
{
    var x = reader as Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader;
    var dec = x.GetOracleDecimal(i);
    value = dec.ToString();
}
```

Every other field in the universe will simply work with reader.GetValue()
It's what makes Oracle special :)

Comment: Except, what if you are using the reader[] operator?? There has to be an reader["namedColumn"] Decimal getter() function that does not require an index integer argument, when not using 'i' index, such as, x["namedColumn"].GetOracleDecimal(), right?  But there isn't. (-:

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who uses the `reader[]` operator to access column information, I've got a method that handles finding the column ordinal & then using Daniel's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67036136/5617618) to fix the issue with casting to a decimal.

```
public string GetColumnValue(
    IDataReader reader,
    string columnName
)
{
    int columnOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal(columnName);

    if (reader.IsDBNull(columnOrdinal))
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (reader.GetFieldType(columnOrdinal).Name.ToUpper() == "DECIMAL")
    {
        return (reader as OracleDataReader).GetOracleDecimal(columnOrdinal).ToString();
    }

    return reader[columnName].ToString();
}
```

This method will get the result based on the column name you provide, and convert the value to a string. You can then use the `Convert` standard library to get the right type from there.